# Buscar propiedad en un array de objetos Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un array de objetos y una función que recibe el nombre de una de sus propiedades. Si esa propiedad se encuentra en el array, me debe devolver un array con todos los valores de esa propiedad.

Este es mi código y me devuelve `undefined`:

```js
const products = [
  { name: 'Pantalla', price: 1300, quantity: 4 },
  { name: 'Scanner', price: 2700, quantity: 3 },
  { name: 'Mouse', price: 400, quantity: 7 },
  { name: 'Teclado', price: 1200, quantity: 9 },
];

function getAllPropValues(propName) {
  for (const product of products) {
    if (Object.keys(product) === propName) {
      return Object.values(product.name);
    }
  }
}

console.log(getAllPropValues('name')); // undefined
```

Y me debería devolver lo siguiente:

```
console.log(getAllPropValues("name"));  // ["Pantalla", "Scanner", "Mouse", "Teclado"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes declarar un array y hacer **`push`** a los valores de la clave que se ingresa como parámetro en tu función, recuerda que esto es recursivo por el [**`for...of`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), así que estarías iterando a todo el array **`products`** y devolviendo los valores en el array **`valores`**, ejemplo:

```js
const products = [
  { name: 'Pantalla', price: 1300, quantity: 4 },
  { name: 'Scanner', price: 2700, quantity: 3 },
  { name: 'Mouse', price: 400, quantity: 7 },
  { name: 'Teclado', price: 1200, quantity: 9 },
];

function getAllPropValues(propName) {
  const valores = [];
  for (const product of products) {
    valores.push(product[propName]);
  }
  return valores;
}
console.log(getAllPropValues("name"));
console.log(getAllPropValues("price"));
console.log(getAllPropValues("quantity"));
```

---

Y ahora la idea es que si la clave que recibe tu función no existe en el objeto, no pushee ningún valor. Esto lo podrías hacer con [**`includes`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) para validar que si la clave del objeto es igual al parámetro que recibe tu función, si cumple pushea al array, de lo contrario no pushea nada y devuelve el array vacío:

```
if (Object.keys(product).includes(propName)) {
  valores.push(product[propName]);
}
```

---

Código final:

```js
const products = [
  { name: 'Pantalla', price: 1300, quantity: 4 },
  { name: 'Scanner', price: 2700, quantity: 3 },
  { name: 'Mouse', price: 400, quantity: 7 },
  { name: 'Teclado', price: 1200, quantity: 9 },
];

function getAllPropValues(propName) {
  const valores = [];
  for (const product of products) {
    if (Object.keys(product).includes(propName)) {
      valores.push(product[propName]);
    }
  }
  return valores;
}
console.log(getAllPropValues("name"));
console.log(getAllPropValues("price"));
console.log(getAllPropValues("quantity"));
console.log(getAllPropValues("otra clave")); // no pushea nada...
```

Comment: Excenlente explicación, Cris. Solo comentar un detalle al op: si haces `return` dentro de un bucle, saldrá en el primer elemento y nunca recorrerá todos. Haz un `console.log(Object.keys(product))` antes del if y verás porque nunca entraba en el.

Comment: Cierto! me olvidé mencionarlo, gracias de todas formas :-).